# Different definitions of Casimir element

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I read about the Casimir element just recently and I found it a bit difficult to wrap my mind around the definition(s). In fact, I have seen two different definitions. For concreteness, let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of a connected (semi-simple) Lie group $G$, and $\pi\colon G\to GL(V)$ a group representation of $G$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. (I assume for simplicity that an orthonormal basis relative to the Killing form exists.)

1. (Definition as a matrix using the derived representation) For an orthonormal basis $\{X_i\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, the Casimir element is defined to be the matrix $\Omega=\sum d\pi(X_i)^2$ in $\text{Mat}(n\times n)$.
2. (Definition as an element in the center of enveloping Lie algebra) For an orthonormal basis $\{X_i\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ the Casimir element is defined by $\Omega=\sum X_i^2$ in $\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.

My question is how are these two definitions related? 
For instance, if $\pi$ is irreducible, it is obvious to me from Schur's Lemma that $\Omega$ in the first definition is a scalar matrix. Can this result be somehow transferred to the $\Omega$ in the second definition? More generally, is any of these closer to `the right way' of thinking about the Casimir element?

Any explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The second way is closer to rigth understanding of the Casimir elements. This approаch can be extended  to define a generalized Casimir elements: Let $\{u_i \}$  and $\{u_i^* \}$  be basis of two dual representations  of Lie algebra $g$ in its universal enveloping agebra $\mathfrak{g}$.  Then the element 
$$
\sum_i u_i u^*_i,
$$
lies in the center $Z(g)$ and called  the generalised Casimir element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the last line I guess you mean $Z(\mathfrak{U}(\mathfrak{g})$. Do you have any thoughts on the relation between the two definitions that I have written in my question?